# AbstractTableModel isCellEditable method is not called

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to edit a column with class type Product. But sometimes the isCellEditable() is not called. Sometimes it works as expected.

```
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
  {
    boolean isEditable = false;
    if (getColumnClass(column).equals(Product.class))
    {
      isEditable = true;
    }
    return isEditable;
  }
```

The class object is also created when the isCellEditable() needs to be called.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue

Comment: As you can see from the `isCellEditable` method parameters, whether a cell is editable or not is based on the row and or column numbers.  I'm not sure the column class types have been set at the time this method is called.

Comment: Did you override the getColumnClass(...) method? By default it returns Object. Without a proper [mre], there is not much we can do to help. Code doesn't just randomly work sometimes.